# highlighting only the First string in Search

Tags: javascript, replace

I am new to JavaScript. I am facing a problem with my javascript code. I am trying to use the string replace method to highlight the searched text.
But My function only highlight the First string that it find and dont highlight another strings !!
How can I fix it to find all strings that I type in search .
Here is my Code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
    function search()
    {
        var s = document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = s.replace(document.getElementById('txt').value , '<span style="color:red">'+document.getElementById("txt").value+'</span>')
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txt" value="search..." onfocus="value=''" />
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="search" onclick="search()"/>
    <p id="p1">
        Type any word from this paragraph in the box above, then click the "Search" button to highlight it red      
    </p>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `split` and `join` like so:

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = s.split(document.getElementById('txt').value).join('<span style="color:red">'+document.getElementById("txt").value+'</span>');
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ct4WU/) to play with.

Answer (score 4):

[Regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with `g` *global* flag will help:

```
function search() {
    var p1 = document.getElementById("p1"),
        value = document.getElementById("txt").value,
        regex = new RegExp("\\b" + value + "\\b", "gi"),
        rwith = '<span style="color: red;">$&</span>';

    p1.innerHTML = p1.innerHTML.replace(regex, rwith);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/guC4j/

Comment: Much better implementation than what I wrote. +1

Comment: Is there a way to easily escape the `value` such that if the search string contains something that can be interpreted by a regular expression it would be ignored? I can see the other side though in that this allows you to build regular expression searches too, which is cool. :)

Comment: @MarcBaumbach There is no need in escaping, since `RegExp` constructor accepts only escaped special characters, i.e. not `\s` but `\\s`.

Comment: @VisioN Well, one example that's interesting is a search string like `t[a-z]+`. It's actually a pretty powerful way to allow searching, but I was wondering if there's similarly an easy way to block it with this method if desired.

Comment: @MarcBaumbach Besides it gives you a perfect way to use regular expressions in a search input box :)